# Problem with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql

I am having a problem with accessing SQL Server in visual studio. I am reading in a csv file and putting it into a SQL Server database. I am using DBAccees to do this, however, when I run the application, I get a "Login Failed for user" error. I am not sure why it is doing this as the username and password is right.

```
DBAccess _dba = new DBAccess("server=servername;database=name;password=password;user=username");
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the username parameter in the connection string is wrong.
change it to:

```
DBAccess _dba = new DBAccess
                ("server=servername; database=name;password=password;uid=username");
```

Comment: if i want have to no password, do i need to put password= or just not put it in there at all

Comment: well, I am currently using my local machine as the server...Would that cause any problems...and i cant get sql server authentication to work..only windows authentication

Comment: Are you able to connect to the server using SQL Server Management Studio and using SQL Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If you cant get SQL server authentication to work, have you verified you have a correctly configured SQL user setup?  With access to the correct database?  If you don't need to use SQL authentication and want to use Integrated use this for a connection string:

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;